# Why can't I use an HOC in React here?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this HOC, I've omitted code for clarity:

```
const TestWrapper = (Component) => {
  return function() {
    return <Component />
  }
}
```

Which is called like this:

```
const b = <Breadcrumbs items={ crumbs } />

const ConnectedAppHeader = TestWrapper(b);

return (
   <div>
     <ConnectedAppHeader />
   </div>
)
```

I have a component named `Breadcrumbs` which takes a prop. This runs OK if I just use it with  `<Breadcrumbs items={ crumbs } />`. But as soon as I try to wrap it in the `TestWrapper` I get this error:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I've obviously got my rendering type wrong, but I'm stuck. How do I get this HOC working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HOCs expect *component functions* as arguments -- not an actual *instance* of the component function. You're trying to pass a `Breadcrumbs` element when you're supposed to pass *the* `Breadcrumbs` function/class itself. That's because you're creating a new element in `TestWrapper` -- you can't  an element from an element, you have to create an element from the actual class or function.

For example, you could modify the wrapper to become this:

```
const TestWrapper = (Component, items) => {
  return function() {
    return <Component items={items} />
  }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
const ConnectedAppHeader = TestWrapper(Breadcrumbs, crumbs);
```

Comment: ok, I sort of understand that, can you post the syntax for please

Comment: @Rory Posted an example.

Comment: Thank you so much. From your comments and code I understand now. I'll mark up your answer