# HOC as an App Wrapper for React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, higher-order-components

I wanted to have an app HOC that wraps each component view.
This HOC authenticates user and sets Google Analytics tracking.
I'm upgrading to Router 4, and having an issue with making it work.

It's giving me the following error -

```
TypeError: (0 , _AppWrapper2.default) is not a function
```

Which is likely related to how I am creating the HOC.
Any ideas?

routes.js

```
export default (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={AppWrapper(Home)} />
    <Route exact path="/channels" component={AppWrapper(Channels)} />
 </Switch>
```

);

```
const AppWrapper = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class AppWrapperComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const page = this.props.location.pathname;
      this.trackPage(page);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      const currentPage = this.props.location.pathname;
      const nextPage = nextProps.location.pathname;

      if (currentPage !== nextPage) {
        this.trackPage(nextPage);
      }
    }

    trackPage = page => {
      GoogleAnalytics.set({
        page,
        ...options,
      });
      GoogleAnalytics.pageview(page);
    };

   render() {
     return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isMounted && !window.devToolsExtension && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && <DevTools />}
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props.chidren} />
      </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099094/react-hoc-render-wrapped-component this could be helpful

Comment: you need to import AppWrapper in routes.js with curly brackets, like this: import { AppWrapper } from './wrapper'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not exporting `AppWrapper`. If you import it with `import AppWrapper from ..`, add this line at the end of `AppWrapper.js`:

```
export default AppWrapper;
```

or replace the const declaration with

```
export default (WrappedComponent) => { ..
```

If you import it with `import {AppWrapper} from ..`, you can insert an `export` before the `const`:

```
export const AppWrapper = (WrappedComponent) => {
```